# python: list append - each time create a new list?

Tags: python, list, append

What's the underlining machanism of append in python's list?

IE. `a = [1,2,3]; a.append(3)` then a is [1,2,3,3]

Dose python actually create a new list tmp [1,2,3,3], then assign that list to a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't. List is mutable type in Python which means the append operation would change the original structure in memory.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> id(a)
4325551112
>>> a.append(4)
>>> id(a)
4325551112
```

this is it.

Answer (score 1):

No it modifies the original list , but does not return a new one, as lists are mutable.

to give you an example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
print a.append(4)
```

will return None, as append does not return a new list.

```
print a.pop(1)
```

will print 1 as pop removes and returns 1